# Jbehave - thucydides multi-thread execution of selected stories

Tags: multithreading, jbehave, thucydides

my organization is using selenium automation framework designed using Jbehave-Thucydides-Maven. The framework consists of 1500+ tests, however, not all are required to be executed every time. Whenever we execute small batch (say 10 scripts or so), all 1500+ scripts are loaded in system and filtering is done on "Meta" tags (which are passed at time of execution) to execute selected 10 scripts. This is causing high overall execution time wherein actual scripts execution takes only 10 mins whereas loading the scripts and filtering takes 15+ mins making high total execution time. Below is the snap-shot of the maven pom which is used to trigger the multi-thread execution. Could you please advise what changes are required so that only required 10 scripts are loaded in system rather than whole 1500+ scripts.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cl2Oh.png)